# How to make this location-based complex query more efficient?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query, postgis

I'm building a dating app, and it needs to filter based on several conditions:

- Distance
- Gender and Orientation
- Liked or unliked status

I'm using Postgis extension. In this case "my own" profile ID is `2` so I'm filtering out my own profile, people I have "liked", and people who have "unliked" me. I'm also adding `WHERE` statements for matching genders and orientations, lastly, I'm restricting locations.

This is the query:

```
SELECT
    "profile"."id" AS "profile_id",
    "profile"."name" AS "profile_name",
    "profile"."gender" AS "profile_gender",
    "profile"."gender_interests" AS "profile_gender_interests",
    "profile"."orientation" AS "profile_orientation",
    "profile"."orientation_interests" AS "profile_orientation_interests",
    ST_AsGeoJSON("profile"."location")::json AS "profile_location",
    ST_Distance(location, ST_SetSRID (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[60.40,24.02]}'), ST_SRID(location))) / 1000 AS "profile_distance"
FROM
    "profile" "profile"
WHERE
    "profile"."id" NOT IN(
        SELECT
            "interactions"."interacted_profile_id" AS "id" FROM "interaction" "interactions"
        WHERE
            "interactions"."interacting_profile_id" = 2)
    AND "profile"."id" NOT IN(
        SELECT
            "interactions"."interacting_profile_id" AS "id" FROM "interaction" "interactions"
        WHERE
            "interactions"."interacted_profile_id" = 2
            AND "interactions"."likes" = FALSE)
    AND 'man' = ANY ("profile"."gender_interests")
    AND "profile"."gender" IN('non_binary', 'woman')
    AND 'straight' = ANY ("profile"."orientation_interests")
    AND "profile"."orientation" IN('straight')
    AND "profile"."id" != 2
    AND ST_DWithin (location, ST_SetSRID (ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type":"Point","coordinates":[60.40,24.02]}'), ST_SRID(location)), 10000)
ORDER BY
    profile_distance ASC
LIMIT 10
```

When I'm using `EXPLAIN` to explain the complexity to me, this is what I get:

```
 Limit  (cost=441.31..467.71 rows=1 width=177)
   ->  Result  (cost=441.31..467.71 rows=1 width=177)
         ->  Sort  (cost=441.31..441.31 rows=1 width=177)
               Sort Key: ((st_distance(profile.location, (st_setsrid('0101000020E610000093FFC9DFBD154E40D1402C9B39F03840'::geometry, st_srid(profile.location)))::geography, true) / '1000'::double precision))
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on profile  (cost=35.50..441.30 rows=1 width=177)
                     Recheck Cond: ((gender = ANY ('{man,woman}'::profile_gender_enum[])) AND (orientation = 'straight'::profile_orientation_enum))
                     Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (id <> 2) AND ('man'::profile_gender_interests_enum = ANY (gender_interests)) AND ('straight'::profile_orientation_interests_enum = ANY (orientation_interests)) AND st_dwithin(location, (st_setsrid('0101000020E610000093FFC9DFBD154E40D1402C9B39F03840'::geometry, st_srid(location)))::geography, '10000'::double precision, true))
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_b82abe3b232741ee19906c3825"  (cost=0.00..8.45 rows=15 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ((gender = ANY ('{man,woman}'::profile_gender_enum[])) AND (orientation = 'straight'::profile_orientation_enum))
                     SubPlan 1
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on interaction interactions  (cost=4.21..14.37 rows=8 width=4)
                             Recheck Cond: (interacting_profile_id = 2)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_1e8a75ba16199ade69cb1f3c39"  (cost=0.00..4.21 rows=8 width=0)
                                   Index Cond: (interacting_profile_id = 2)
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on interaction interactions_1  (cost=4.19..12.65 rows=4 width=4)
                             Recheck Cond: (interacted_profile_id = 2)
                             Filter: (NOT likes)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "IDX_7e717fee4ad67f7c9ad011ed3f"  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=4 width=0)
                                   Index Cond: ((interacted_profile_id = 2) AND (likes = false))
```

How can I improve the performance of this query?

Update. Schemas:

```
                                                  Table "public.profile"
        Column         |                 Type                 | Collation | Nullable |               Default
-----------------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                              |           | not null | nextval('profile_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at            | timestamp without time zone          |           | not null | now()
 updated_at            | timestamp without time zone          |           | not null | now()
 type                  | profile_type_enum                    |           | not null | 'solo'::profile_type_enum
 name                  | character varying                    |           | not null |
 bio                   | text                                 |           |          |
 location              | geography(Point,4326)                |           |          |
 distance              | double precision                     |           |          |
 gender                | profile_gender_enum                  |           |          |
 gender_interests      | profile_gender_interests_enum[]      |           |          |
 orientation           | profile_orientation_enum             |           |          |
 orientation_interests | profile_orientation_interests_enum[] |           |          |
Indexes:
    "PK_3dd8bfc97e4a77c70971591bdcb" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "IDX_077a36940fcc2bcb48c8b12a24" btree (orientation)
    "IDX_4cc893cdb42a39dd9d562075ac" btree (gender)
    "IDX_83201725f7096a4ac3d4edf82b" gist (location)
    "IDX_89c62d157f55da60b367b35765" btree (gender_interests)
    "IDX_b82abe3b232741ee19906c3825" btree (gender, orientation)
    "IDX_e8d60ae9af88814e718a956c3d" btree (orientation_interests)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "photo" CONSTRAINT "FK_31f2c69cd18b8442b80b546da31" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
    TABLE "interaction" CONSTRAINT "FK_54a314b7a96f6c711cdce52cc7f" FOREIGN KEY (interacted_profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
    TABLE "interaction" CONSTRAINT "FK_6e2eb3f349c82b9742445d15e00" FOREIGN KEY (interacting_profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
    TABLE "user_profiles_profile" CONSTRAINT "FK_94241409cb866a92a992511f3c8" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)

                                              Table "public.interaction"
         Column         |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 id                     | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('interaction_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at             | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | now()
 likes                  | boolean                     |           | not null |
 interacting_profile_id | integer                     |           |          |
 interacted_profile_id  | integer                     |           |          |
Indexes:
    "PK_9204371ccb2c9dab5428b406413" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "IDX_1e8a75ba16199ade69cb1f3c39" UNIQUE, btree (interacting_profile_id, interacted_profile_id)
    "IDX_6e2eb3f349c82b9742445d15e0" btree (interacting_profile_id)
    "IDX_7e717fee4ad67f7c9ad011ed3f" btree (interacted_profile_id, likes)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "FK_54a314b7a96f6c711cdce52cc7f" FOREIGN KEY (interacted_profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
    "FK_6e2eb3f349c82b9742445d15e00" FOREIGN KEY (interacting_profile_id) REFERENCES profile(id)
```

Comment: It may help if you posted the schemas

Comment: @RohitGupta added.

Comment: We don't know what the current performance is.  Please do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Preferably turn on track_io_timing first.